Handle custom domains (CNAME) with a wildcard certificate Apache
I need help setting up an Apache web server to handle custom domain (CNAME) records with HTTPS.
I have a web application hosted on app.example.com with an Apache server. I have added the Custom Domain feature. Using this, users can set up their subdomain instead of app.example.com. For that, I have added an A record for domain.example.com which is pointing to the same server as app.example.com.
Now on the Apache side, I've wildcard configuration to handle *.example.com. Those users who have not setup CNAME can use app.example.com but those who have setup CNAME should be able to use the web application on their subdomain. So if I have set up CNAME for live.userdomain.com and added a CNAME entry to domain.example.com, then when I visit live.userdomain.com, I should see the content of domain.example.com (which is app.example.com). All these are working fine.
But, the issue is SSL. I have wildcard SSL on my Apache web server. app.example.com is working fine on HTTPS. However, the CNAME subdomains have an issue with HTTPS. When I enter live.userdomain.com, it returns an "ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" error. This is the detailed error "This server could not prove that it is live.userdomain.com; its security certificate is from example.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.".
Here is the Apache config file,
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias *

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAlias *.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public

<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/example.com/STAR.example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/example.com/STAR_mymeet_io.pem
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/example.com/STAR.example.com.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>

Can anyone please suggest how to fix this?

The error message is pretty clear. Make Apache send the correct certificate. You have included no configuration details, so we can't really tell you what's wrong.

Hi, I've added the config file now. The question is, how to handle the custom domains? Like, live.userdomain.com?

A CNAME record only applies to DNS address resolving.  For a web browser it doesn't make a difference how a hostname is configured at the DNS level, because a web browser only uses the hostname from the URL in the requests it generates.  When somebody enters https://hostname in their address bar, your server needs to present a TLS certificate that includes hostname or your site vistors will get an TLS warning/error message, regardless of how hostname gets pointed to your server,  hostname IN CNAME app.example.com.  or directly with the IP via hostname IN A  192.168.1.1  no difference

CNAME is irrelevant - you need a certificate for the name in the URL. This means your wildcard certificate is of no use if the only use of your domain is inside the CNAME target but not the name in the URL. See Certificates, and multiple CNAME records, SSL certificates and DNS CNAME.

@SteffenUllrich OK, so how do I handle SSL for user-added custom domains?

You need to explicitly add these domains (as seen in the URL, not the CNAME target)  to your server and get certificates for them, same as you would do with your own domains.

@SteffenUllrich You are right. I had to generate SSL for those custom domains. I could use Let's Encrypt to generate SSL but I used Caddy to generate SSL on the fly. I appreciate your help.
